# Use data from volume during container build in docker compose

Tags: docker-compose

I need to share data between containers with docker compose. Here `shared_data_setup` container should seed the `shared` ***volume with data to be used during build of the `app` container***. However when I run this, `app` container `/shared` is empty. Is there a way to achieve this ?

```
services:
    # This will setup some seed data to be used in other containers
    shared_data_setup:
        build: ./shared_data_setup/
        volumes:
            - shared:/shared

    app:
        build: ./app/
        volumes:
            - shared:/shared

        depends_on:
            - shared_data_setup

volumes:
    shared:
       driver: local
```

Comment: `volume with data to be used during build of the app container` It cannot be done https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/3275/how-to-populate-docker-volumes-in-a-build-step-to-be-used-by-a-different-contain

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the version of the `docker-compose.yml` file:

```yaml
version: "3"

services:
    # This will setup some seed data to be used in other containers
    shared_data_setup:
        build: ./shared_data_setup/
        volumes:
            - shared:/shared

    app:
        build: ./app/
        volumes:
            - shared:/shared

        depends_on:
            - shared_data_setup

volumes:
    shared:
       driver: local
```

**Edit: Results:**

```sh
# Test volume from app
$ docker-compose exec app bash
root@e652cb9e5c46:/# ls -l /shared
total 0
root@e652cb9e5c46:/# touch /shared/test
root@e652cb9e5c46:/# exit

# Test volume from shared_data_setup
$ docker-compose exec shared_data_setup bash
root@b21ead1a7354:/# ls -l /shared
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Feb 26 11:23 test
root@b21ead1a7354:/# exit
```

Comment: It's omitted from the sudo code in my question but I do have it specified

Comment: I have tested it like this and works properly. Is it possible that something else is being mounted on the same path?

Comment: Added results from above YAML. **Note:** I used `image: nginx` instead of the original `build`, as I don't have the `Dockerfile`s.

Comment: I am trying to access the content of the shared files from within the Dockerfile, not at container runtime

Comment: It's impossible to access volumes during build. Try a different approach.